# React Array of components - click handler issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

Using React 15.6.1
I'm making a QA forum and here's the code for rendering a single answer with multiple replies:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import bindHelper from '../util/bindHelper';

const AnswerStub = (props) => (
  <div className={props.wrapperClass}>
    <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: props.answer.body }} />
    <div className="pull-right">
      <span>{props.answer.author.name}</span><br />
      <span>{props.answer.postDate}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
)

class Answer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      key: props.answer._id,
      replyTo: false,
      replyText: ''
    }
    bindHelper(this);
  }

  _handleReply(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(event.target.id);
    console.log(this.state.key);
    this.setState({ replyTo: !this.state.replyTo });
  }

  _handleClear(event) {
    this.setState({ replyText: '' });
  }

  _handleReplyChange(event) {
    this.setState({ replyText: event.target.value });
  }

  _handlePostReply(event) {
    //TODO: dispatch event handler for reply
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="row answer">
        <div className="col-md-1">
          <span className={this.props.answer.accepted ? "glyphicon glyphicon-ok" : ""} />
        </div>
        <AnswerStub wrapperClass="col-md-11" answer={this.props.answer} />
        <div className="comments col-md-12">
          {this.props.answer.replies && this.props.answer.replies.map((reply, i) => <AnswerStub key={i} wrapperClass="comment-single" answer={reply} />)}
        </div>

        <div className="clearfix" />

        {/* REPLY OPTION */}
        <div className="col-md-offset-1 col-md-11">
          <a id={`reply_${this.state.key}`} href="" onClick={this.handleReply.bind(this)}>
            {this.state.replyTo ? "Cancel" : "Post a Reply"}
          </a>
          {this.state.replyTo &&
            <div>
              <textarea className="col-md-11 form-control" rows="3"
                value={this.state.replyText} onChange={this.handleReplyChange} />
              <br />
              <button className="col-md-2 btn btn-default" onClick={this.handleClear}>Clear</button>
              <button className="col-md-2 btn btn-primary pull-right" onClick={this.handlePostReply}>Post</button>
            </div>
          }
        </div>

        <div className="clearfix" />
        <br />

      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Answer;
```

I am calling this in another component like

```
{this.props.answers && this.props.answers.map((ans,i) => <Answer key={ans._id} answer={ans} />)}
```

But when i click on a reply, the reply textbox for that opens, for every other case the last textbox keeps getting toggled no matter which link I click.

Sample output on the console:

```
59ba431d518a97998d310bd9
reply_59bba3b82219703fb84d07e7
59bba3b82219703fb84d07e7
reply_59ba431d518a97998d310bd9
59bba3b82219703fb84d07e7
reply_59bba3b82219703fb84d07e7
59bba3b82219703fb84d07e7
```

The target element is correct, but it's accessing the wrong state.

Shouldn't the states of each of the Answer component be separate? I cant figure out what is going on. And yes, I'm a beginner in React!

EDIT

[bindHelper](https://gist.github.com/royNiladri/fdf9638ef0d59f189dd233bd7bb66906#file-thisbinder-js) is a helper function i wrote to bind the `this` reference.

Comment: Can you rephhrase this part? *But when i click on a reply, the reply textbox for that opens, for every other case the last textbox keeps getting toggled no matter which link I click.*

Comment: Assume a question has 2 answers. When I click the reply link for first, the first reply box opens, as expected. When I click the same same link, I am expecting it to close, but the second reply box opens. All subsequent clicks (on either of the links) simply toggles the second reply box.

Comment: Try it without the bindHelper (bind the methods manually) and let us know if anything changed

Comment: You also have `onClick={this.handleReply.bind(this)}` at some point. Shouldn't it be `onClick={this.handleReply}` since you are handling the binding in the constructor?

Comment: Well, that does solve the problem indeed! But can you help out what is going wrong with the helper?

Comment: Yeah, i was trying a manual bind but had the bindhelper line as well. Commenting that out solved it. But even without the bind and just the helper, the problem was there.

Comment: So, `onClick={this.handleReply.bind(this)}` was the problem? Or the `bindHelper`?
 Sorry, I lost you :)

Comment: The `bindHelper` was the problem. The `.bind` was a half baked solution i was trying. Need help realizing what the issue was with the helper. Seems to work normally when there are no repeated components.

Comment: Give me a few minutes to read it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so the problem is that in `bindHelper` you are messing with the prototype of each `Answer` instance.

At this point I have to remind you that all `Answer` instances share the same prototype. If it helps you you can find the prototype of an object like this (and is 100% cross-browser compatible too):

`object.constructor.prototype`

So, when with each `Answer` instance you add a new key with the `replacement` part to the prototype object, you are essentially replacing the one that was added by the previous call of `bindHelper`

So for example, you have the first `Answer` instance. You call `bindHelper(this)`. Now `this.constructor.prototype` (or `this.__proto__`, it's the same) has a new property `handleReply`, which is bbound to this instance of `Answer`.

On the second `Answer` instance, when you call `bindHelper(this)` you are again operating on the very same `this.constructor.prototype` (`this.__proto__`) as before. It's the same because all instances of `Answer` share it. So, you go there again, and you replace the already existing `handleReply` which was bound to the previous `Answer` instance, to a new `handleReply` which is bound to the `Answer` instance.

And this happens for everything, as a result, the `handleReply` method on the prototype is bound only to the last `Answer` instance, thus your error.

**UPDATE**

Here's how your `bindHelper` could work (sorry for formatting errors, I am on my phone)

```
export default function bindHelper(obj, signature='_handle', replacement='handle'){

  // iterate over all the own properties in the object prototype

  for(let key of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj.constructor.prototype)){

    //check for the ones that begin with '_handle' by default or the provided starting signature

    if(key.startsWith(signature)){

      obj[key.replace(signature, replacement)] = obj.constructor.prototype[key].bind(obj);

    }

  }

}
```

As a personal thought I do find this function quite limiting, as you'll find cases where you may need methods whose names start with something other than one pattern

Comment: Okay!! Sad to realize my little helper hack was a bad idea. Will revert back to the old school way of binding in the constructor. Thanks!

Comment: Actually you can make it work. I'll reply again with code when I return home. Or you can think about it in the meantime ;)

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: Yeah, agreed this has limitations, but the idea was to save some monotonous typing. We can always manually bind function which do not conform to a pattern.